# Facebook share with custom message

Tags: html, facebook

There's a quiz on project site where you answer some questions and based on answers get a result. The result differs from time to time, but client demands, that the result (custom message) should be able to be shared on facebook.

All I want to do is share the url to the quiz with a custom message, ie: 'I answered 6 out of 10 questions in quiz about History, what about you?', but yes, Like button doesn't do it, share button is kind of dead and have no idea about other solutions.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

## update

Seriously... There is no way to perform such a simple task?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customize message field on Facebook Share](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591655/customize-message-field-on-facebook-share)

Comment: @Mike, How come a question asked in 2011 is a duplicate of question asked in 2012? :O

Comment: Haha good question. I think because the answer is out of date and the functionality provided in it has been removed. So the newer answer is the one I eventually found that helped me, but this one was the one I wasted a good chunk of time on first to much frustration.

Answer (score 9):

What about [Feed dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) ?

Direct users to this link to get a sharer-like dialog:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=123050457758183&
  link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Dialogs%20provide%20a%20simple,%20consistent%20interface%20for%20applications%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

Comment: Huh, any chance of doing it the "no application" way?

Comment: Okay, looks like this is it, probably even the only way.

Comment: cV2: you need to create a Facebook app here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps and you'll get the app_id to use.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like facebook ignores the message parameter since 2011:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/510/