# How to change Facebook's shared title and message?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to Facebook Sharing API. When I put the Facebook Share button in my website, both the message and the title are the URL. Here's the screenshot:

[image]

There's even no thumbnails even though there's plenty of pictures in the page.

I have seen other pages that automatically use the first paragraph as the Facebook's message

Is there any specific site layout that I must follow?

**Note**: I'm using AddThis, so I don't think I can change the code

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996483/facebook-share-with-custom-message I find this result, I think it suits you.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. But since I'm using AddThis, I don't think I can change the PHP code

Comment: Have you implemented [Open Graph tags](http://ogp.me/) for website?

Comment: @AnveshSaxena Yeah, I already tried to put `og:description`, `title`, etc but none works. Is the **AddThis** block should be put inside the same container as the content?

Comment: @DarcCode the position of the **AddThis** doesn't matters as long as its script is in the end of the add blocks. Also check the detail you can see from the [open graph debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for all the replies. When I upload my site to online server, the Facebook Share works perfectly. Maybe FB API can't access the image and data from localhost

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved when I uploaded the site on Online server. Maybe the API has problem retrieving data from Localhost.

Cheers :)